# What is the best way to create PDF files in Azure storage blob using Python?

Tags: python, azure, pdf-generation, fpdf, azure-function-app

I am new to Python and I came up with a requirement for created PDF files with data available in SQL server using Python script. As I researched, there are many libraries which can be used for this purpose but most of their approach is to generate HTML string then convert it into PDF file in a local directory. But none of them suggested how to do it on Azure storage.
 I am having an Azure function app which connects to DB and reads data, now I need to create PDF using this data. Since Azure function app is a serverless source and can't relay on a physical directory at all. 
 So I should be able to create a string with data and convert them into PDF and upload them directly to Azre storage.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from fpdf import FPDF

def generate_PDF():
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", 12)
    pdf.cell(w=0,h=0,txt="This is sample pdf",align="L")
    pdf.output('demo.pdf')

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')
            c_pdf = req_body.get('cpdf')
            if c_pdf == 'Y':
                generate_PDF()

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!, create PDF (cpdf) is set to {c_pdf}")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body", status_code=400)
```

I am using FPDF library, and it creates pdf file in the current working directory.
Suggest me the best way for my approach.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide the code you have tried? Besides, you have tried to save the pdf file as stream then upload the stream to azure blob?

Comment: I added code snippet I used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

sdk

```
pip install azure-storage-blob fpdf aiohttp
```

code

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient
from fpdf import FPDF


async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=jimtestdiag924;AccountKey=uxz4AtF0A4tWBcPHwgbFAfdinvLEZpJtAu1MYVWD/xYCYDcLLRb8Zhp5lxR2/2rQ2P1OrxZwWarEoWyDSZ7Q+A==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
    pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Hello World!')
    s = pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1')
    logging.info(s)
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    async with blob_service_client:
            container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client('testupload')
            try:
                # Create new Container in the Service
                await container_client.create_container()
            except Exception as ex:
                pass
            # Get a new BlobClient
            blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client('demo.pdf')
            await blob_client.upload_blob(s, blob_type="BlockBlob",content_settings=ContentSettings( content_type='application/pdf'))
            



    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
             status_code=400
        )
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to separate main method and pdf creation part, but when I did execution not going to pdf part at all.